# Pokemon Go login help?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was randomly logged out of my account yesterday and had signed in the Pokemon site with a fake email. But now when I made a new account, I signed out then I was signed in perfectly but when I try to log in with my old account it says I need to activate my account with my fake email! But my new account doesn't have this problem. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Pokemon website](http://www.pokemon.com/us/) and update the email address associated with your Pokemon Trainer account to one that you can access. You can create a new one that you only use for this if you are concerned about using your regular email.